# Mopidy Extension: 'ThreadingFuture' object does not support indexing

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a Mopidy extension. The following codes prints the error message below.

```
 def switch_channel(self, input_event):
        channelIndex = input_event['channel']-1
        track = self.core.tracklist.get_tl_tracks()[channelIndex]
        if self.core.playback.state.get() == core.PlaybackState.PLAYING:
            self.core.playback.play(track)
```

Error:

> File
>   "/home/pi/Documents/python/test_extension/mopidy-radiostar/mopidy_radiostar/frontend.py",
>   line 63, in switch_channel
>       track = self.core.tracklist.get_tl_tracks()[channelIndex] TypeError: 'ThreadingFuture' object does not support indexing

The Mopidy documentation states "Get tracklist as list of mopidy.models.TlTrack.". Why is this not a list?

Comment: Are you using Pykka to aid your Mopidy frontend development?

Comment: Yes it is included. I'm pretty new to python, how is this important?

Comment: It's actually Pykka producing this error, `ThreadingFuture` is a Pykka class and not a Mopidy class.

Comment: So how Can i fix it?

Comment: Honestly, not sure, I've never used Pykka or Mopidy. But at least now you have something more concrete to research or ask about.

Comment: Okay thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.pykka.org/en/latest/#actor-proxies has some more info on how to use actor proxies, which is what `self.core` should be.

With this in mind you want your code to be:

`track = self.core.tracklist.get_tl_tracks().get()[channelIndex]`

This ensures that you fetch the list that the core returns instead of just trying to use the future which is just a promise that the list or an error will be provided at some point.